# How to execute a shell script and use the result in ansible

Tags: linux, unix, automation, ansible, devops

First of all, I'm still an ansible newbie, so please excuse my ignorance.

I don't know if that's even possible, but I'm trying to get the URL produced by this command:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/Radarr/Radarr/releases | grep linux.tar.gz | grep browser_download_url | head -1 | cut -d \" -f 4
```

and use it in play to download the package:

here is my play:

```
  - name: download Radarr
    get_url:
      url: "{{ Radarr_exe_url }}" #should be the url from above
      dest: "{{ Radarr_data_path }}"
    become: true
    become_user: "{{ Radarr_user_name }}"
    notify:
      - Restart Radarr service
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- name:               Get Radar exe url
  shell:              curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/Radarr/Radarr/releases | grep linux.tar.gz | grep browser_download_url | head -1 | cut -d \" -f 4
  register:           shell_output
- set_fact:
    Radarr_exe_url : "{{ shell_output.stdout }}"
```

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov any advice about the right way to parse it in bash?

Comment: I think I could've used `jq` better? but that isn't portable

Answer (score 2):

Here is pure Ansible solution, as calling `shell` commands when there is module available considered bad practice:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - uri:
        url: https://api.github.com/repos/Radarr/Radarr/releases
        return_content: yes
        body_format: json
      changed_when: no
      register: radarr_releases

    - set_fact:
        Radarr_exe_url: "{{ radarr_releases.json | json_query('[0].assets[].browser_download_url') | select('search','linux.tar.gz') | first }}"
```